# Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have this code:

```
pyautogui.click(169, 681)
pyautogui.doubleClick(474, 679)
pyautogui.typewrite(['backspace', 'backspace', 'backspace'])
pyautogui.typewrite('0.00000')
```

It writes only . instead of 0.00000. Why? How to write a cycle that would write 0.00005, then 0.00010, 0.00015 ...

Comment: It is not clear to me what your actual problem is. I suggest you put some more effort into the description of ithe problem you are facing.

Comment: Problem is that the script slhoud write 0.00000 into some place, but only . is written. Zeros are missing.

Comment: Your code with SciTE in foreground does what it should. So your problem seems to depend on something else outside of scope of pyautogui. Maybe the code you run is other one, so the problem is, that you run not really the code you provided? Maybe zeroes are not allowed in the field you type into?